# Open a file from PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

In a program, and obviously being influenced by the way Java does things, I want to read a static file (a log configuration file, actually) from a directory within the interpreter's PYTHONPATH. I know I could do something like:

```python
import foo
a = foo.__path__
conf = open(a[0] + "/logging.conf")
```

but I don't know if this is the "Pythonic" way of doing things. How could I distribute the logging configuration file in a way that my application does not need to be externally configured to read it?

Comment: See this blog: http://dotnot.org/blog/archives/2004/03/06/find-a-file-in-pythons-path/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, that's fine, though I'm not sure you want `a[0]` above (that will just give you the first character of the path), and you should use `os.path.join` instead of just appending `/` to be cross-platform compatible.  You might consider making the path canonical, i.e. `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(foo.__path__))`. Note that it won't work if `__path__` is in a zip file or other import trickery is in use, but I wouldn't worry about that (it's not normal to do so for the main program in Python, unlike Java).

If you do want to support zipped files, there's [pkg_resources](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html), but that's somewhat deprecated at this point (there's no corresponding API I could see in the new [packaging](http://docs.python.org/dev/packaging/) module).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was mostly looking for confirmation that my method is Pythonic enough, so I didn't pay much attention to the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet based on the link Nix posted upthread but written in a more functional style:

```
def search_path(pathname_suffix):
    cands = [os.path.join(d,pathname_suffix) for d in sys.path]
    try:
        return filter(os.path.exists, cands)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```